# Injecting Pressure values in Windows

Tags: java, windows

I am building an application like in which the user can use his Android tablet as a graphics tablet like https://play.google.com/store/search?q=gfxtablet

My server program is in Java and I was successfully able to send stylus coordinates and pressure values to the server from my tablet through UDP and able to draw in applications like Paint, Photoshop etc.

**The problem:**

I am not able to find a way to inject this pressure values in Windows (to draw thick and thin lines depending upon stylus pressure). I know it can be easily done in Linux, but I am not able to find a way for Windows.

I even tried JNA library for Java , but it also does not seem to have the appropriate method to input pressure values. I know the existence of JPEN & JTABLET libraries but these don't allow you to draw in Paint, Photoshop, GIMP etc.

Comment: Perhaps this library already does what you need? [JTablet](http://jtablet.cellosoft.com/develop.html) "provides a simple open-source (zlib license) interface for accessing tablet input in your Java applications."

Comment: it does provides input to my java application, but i want to give that input to windows paint applications (Photoshop, GIMP, paint) to dynamically change brush size depending upon the pressure values.

Comment: Have you encountered [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695566(v=vs.85).aspx) with your JNA approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Robot class in java to simulate native system input events. Then store local variables to test input against and fire those events through the Robot class.

Basically, for Windows Paint, whenever your pressure is greater than the previous pressure, fire a Robot event that sends the key combination CTRL and + to increase brush width.

If you're also testing what application is open, then you can have a separate section of code set up to determine which key combination to send(since in photoshop the keybind is [ and ]), or have a section that allows users to specify what their keybinding is.

While the current iteration uses awt, [Robot is being added to JavaFX/Lombard in 3.0.](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17571)

I'm sure there are better solutions, but this is what I would do until I had something better. :)